# Signing in using the CookieAuthenticationMiddleware in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have been doing multiple tutorials trying to understand how authentication works in ASP.NET Core. I understand the general concept of how middleware processes a request; however, I'm confused on how the `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` exactly works. I understand that it looks for a cookie, which is basically your encrypted identity, and if it is there, it sets your current identity to the values in the cookie.

How does the original cookie get created for the actual `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware`. It seems to me that this middleware is only helpful if there has been a cookie already generated for it to read. To me you would need another authenticator, like a social login, to set the initial cookie. Something like:

```
app.UseCookieAuthenticationMiddleware(...)
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(...)
```

Additionally, how would the Facebook authentication set a cookie that the cookie authentication middleware would recognize? The docs says that once you have created a principal (presumably from the Facebook middleware), you can call:

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(
    "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", 
    principal);
```

Maybe the Facebook middleware calls this to set the cookie, but I don't really understand what this method does.

My question basically comes down to two points: How does the initial cookie get created for cookie auth middleware, and how does `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(...)` trigger the cookie middleware to go create a cookie?

Thanks!

Comment: one great thing about asp.net being open source is you can study the source code. if you want to know more about the internals of the cookie middleware and other security components, you can find the code here https://github.com/aspnet/Security

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does the original cookie get created for the actual CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.

The cookie **authentication** middleware signs in the user and creates the cookie. The cookie **authorization** middleware looks for the cookie values.

To illustrate, here are [a few lines from the `CookieAuthenticationHandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L202-L206), which show the cookie **authentication** middleware setting a cookie.

```
Options.CookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(
    Context,
    Options.CookieName,
    cookieValue,
    cookieOptions);
```

And here are [a few lines from the `DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement : IAuthorizationHandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/Infrastructure/DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement.cs#L23-L30) that show the **authorization** middleware looking for a cookie value that has been added to the context.

```
var user = context.User;
var userIsAnonymous =
    user?.Identity == null ||
    !user.Identities.Any(i => i.IsAuthenticated);
if (!userIsAnonymous)
{
    context.Succeed(requirement);
}
```

You also asked this:

> ...how would the Facebook authentication set a cookie that the cookie authentication middleware would recognize?

Facebook authentication is OAuth authentication, which means that it is at the bottom of the following inheritance hierarchy.

```
IAuthenticationHandler
└── AuthenticationHandler
    └── CookieAuthenticationHandler
    └── RemoteAuthenticationHandler
        └── OAuthHandler
            └── FacebookHandler
```

In Facebook OAuth, `RemoteAuthenticationHander.HandleRemoteCallbackAsync` handles Facebook's response and then makes a call to [`SignInAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/8fcbddc23be1caff41f59f17b90624171fa8e43e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L106).

```
Context.Authentication.SignInAsync(
    Options.SignInScheme, 
    context.Principal, 
    context.Properties);
```

That call to `SignInAsync` is what you hypothesized in your question.

> ...the Facebook middleware calls [SignInAsync] to set the cookie, but I don't really understand what this method does.

What `SignInAsync` does is complicated. The call to `SignInAsync` happens on the instance of `AuthenticationManager` that lives inside the `Context.Authentication` property. That instance is usually the `DefaultAuthenticationManager`. You can see [the full `SignInAsync` call here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/067eb9c6f80cd2e50fdf3b3d1af0fbd94ac7bc33/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationManager.cs#L124-L148), and here is a snippet from it.

```
public override async Task SignInAsync(
    string authenticationScheme, 
    ClaimsPrincipal principal, 
    AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
    ...

        var handler = HttpAuthenticationFeature.Handler;

        var signInContext = new SignInContext(
            authenticationScheme, 
            principal, 
            properties?.Items);

        if (handler != null)
        {
            await handler.SignInAsync(signInContext);
        }

    ...
}
```

In other words, `SignInAsync` calls `SignInAsync` on an authentication handler, which happens to be an instance of an `IAuthenticationHandler` from the inheritance hierarchy.

We eventually arrive at `CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleSigninAsync`, [which will append the cookie to the response.](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/0152691108717bd74cc5f0406e7b745b31c8ca23/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L272-L276) This cookie handler contains the only two calls to `AppendResponseCookie` in the Security repository.

```
protected override async Task HandleSignInAsync(SignInContext signin)
{
    ...

    Options.CookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(
        Context,
        Options.CookieName,
        cookieValue,
        signInContext.CookieOptions);

    ...
}
```

There are a lot of moving parts. Hopefully this answer gives enough of an overview to fill in the missing pieces yourself.